# xDebug cant find my files. Always looks in localhost

Tags: php, xdebug, netbeans-7

1. I'm running win7-64bit, NetBeans 7.1.1 and WampServer 2.2 (which has xDebug)
2. I've configured php.ini (xdebug.remote_enable=on, etc.)
3. I create a directory (**virtual host called example.dev**) and add a test file. (c:/wamp/example/test-xdebug.php)
4. I run debug in NetBeans and the following url displays:

   http://**localhost**/example/test-xdebug.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
5. This fails. The browser coughs up the following error message.

   **Not Found**.

   The requested URL /example/test-xdebug.php was not found on this server.
6. I add the **correct path** to the virtual host, and xDebug **Runs Flawlessly**:

   http://**example.dev**/test-xdebug.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

Tried every configuration I could think of. If this is a php.ini config issue, I sure as heck cant find it. If its a NetBeans issue, there is not an option/interface to modify i (that I can find).

Please illuminate!

thanks
sleeper

Comment: There is a netbeans setting for this; I think it's in the debug configuration part for the server config.

Comment: @Derick I've been all over google, netbeans, stack... **cant find a thing**. Or ...it could be staring me right in the face and I just _"get it"_ (hence, the post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the xdebug.remote_host option in your PHP config? For instance:

`xdebug.remote_host="example.dev"`

Also, is the Netbeans project config correct? Go to File > Project Properties (or right click project and click properties) then select Run Configuration and check the Project URL field.

Comment: The "xdebug.remote_host" setting has nothing to do with it. It will just resolve to the same IP as localhost anyway. But as you say, the setting is indeed in "File > Project Properties (or right click project and click properties) then select Run Configuration and check the Project URL field."

Comment: @Leonard Challis Now were getting somewhere! That seems to work, cuz now I'm getting the dreaded "Waiting for Connection" error. Lemme go see what the heck is up with that.